# PhoneGap DisallowOverscroll not working when use PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova

When i use the online PhoneGap Build tool the DisallowOverscroll is not working on the device. When i directly build from XCode the DisallowOverscroll is recognized.

Does someone has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, use the following code:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the similar issue. Just stick with the XCode. Its more reliable than online build tools !